# How can I automate the line breaks in a cventry with moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I use `moderncv` to do my cv and I have the problem that long words, like "Staatsangehörigkeit" (german for citizenship) exceed the left column of a `cventry`.

This:
`\cventry{\textbf{Staats\-angehörigkeit}}{Deutsch}{}{}{}{}`
prevents that, but I have to break everything by hand, but `babel` could do that for me ...

So how can I tell `moderncv` to break things on the fly?

Oh and is there a way to get rid of these useless last four `{}{}{}{}`

Thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of the first column in `moderncv` with the command `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}` to 3.5 cm. Then you get a unhyphenated word in the first column, which looks much more better than hyphenated words ...

See the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}    

% character encoding
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm} % <=================================
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}  

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                              
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\extrainfo{additional information}  
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}  
\quote{Some quote}                  

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} 
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\cvitem{Staatsangehörigkeit}{Deutsch}
\cventry{\textbf{Staats\-angehörigkeit}}{Deutsch}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

If you do not want to write the "useless last four `{}{}{}{}`" in command `\cventry` you can use command `\cvitem` instead as I showed in my code.  Command `\cventry` is defined with several parameters so you can't leave the empty pairs of `{}` out.